# Can't access Wifi-Cam From OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, node.js, opencv, esp32

Im using a Wifi-Cam called Esp32-Cam and trying to connect to it with openCv. The Node server.js code makes it possible to connect to the module by it's IP address. The code for server.js is given below:

SERVER.JS:

```
  const path = require('path');
  const express = require('express');
  const WebSocket = require('ws');
  const app = express();

  const WS_PORT  = 8888;
  const HTTP_PORT = 8000;

  const wsServer = new WebSocket.Server({port: WS_PORT}, ()=> console.log(`WS Server is listening at 
  ${WS_PORT}`));

  let connectedClients = [];
  wsServer.on('connection', (ws, req)=>{
  console.log('Connected');
  connectedClients.push(ws);

   ws.on('message', data => {
    connectedClients.forEach((ws,i)=>{
        if(ws.readyState === ws.OPEN){
            ws.send(data);
        }else{
            connectedClients.splice(i ,1);
        }
    })
});
});

app.get('/client',(req,res)=>res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './client.html')));
app.listen(HTTP_PORT, ()=> console.log(`HTTP server listening at ${HTTP_PORT}`));
```

CLİENT.HTML:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="">
    <script>
        const img = document.querySelector('img');
        const WS_URL = 'ws:///192.168.1.33:8888';
        const ws = new WebSocket(WS_URL);
        let urlObject;
        ws.onopen = () => console.log(`Connected to ${WS_URL}`);
        ws.onmessage = message => {
            const arrayBuffer = message.data;
            if(urlObject){
                URL.revokeObjectURL(urlObject);
            }
            urlObject = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([arrayBuffer]));
            img.src = urlObject;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I can access the streaming video on the address "http://192.168.1.33:8000/client" with my browser but not on opencv. Here's the code in OpenCv python trying to reach the camera.

OPENCV CODE:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.33:8000/client')
print(cap.isOpened())  //it prints FALSE
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('framee',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
       break
```

I dont understand why i can't access the camera since this esp32 module is just like an IP camera? I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: nodejs works because it is running as a web socket. But your openCV is running as a http server. right?

Comment: Im sorry that i couldnt understand this but i dont know if there is another way of accessing this module from OpenCV. I really would appreciate your advice.